# Pull last number from element containing both numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a page. On it are several divs containing p elements containing both words and numbers. I'd like to be able to run through the page and grab all of the last numbers and display the total.

`<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center" style="padding-top: 10px;">
 <p><b>Upkeep: </b>32 Bux each
 <br>1472 Bux total</p></div>`

In this example div I would want to grab the 1472 and add it to the total. To further complicate things, this is a Chrome extension I'm trying to make so I have no direct control of the page it will render on.

Below is an example of one of my failed attempts which just ends up filling in the #totalupkeep element with **Total Upkeep:  0032,147234,1496022,149600000** which is amusing but, not what I'm going for.

```
var sumdtotal = 0; 
$('div[class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center"] p').each(function() { 
    sumdtotal += $(this).text().match( /\d+/g ); 
    $(this).css( "background-color", "red" ); 
}); 
$("#totalupkeep").text(sumdtotal);`
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to parse the value you're getting using `Number($(this).text().match( /\d+/g ));`

Comment: Won't that grab all of the numbers? I'm trying to only grab the 1472 in the example div.

Comment: I tried it using your line and it returns NaN

Comment: Add your HTML content to the post please.